# Elasticsearch having count(*)= n

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

I have a simple index (in elasticsearch) and need to execute a query that is available in SQL databases.

my-index structure:

```
'{"id":"1","userid":"1"}'
'{"id":"2","userid":"1"}'
'{"id":"3","userid":"1"}'
'{"id":"4","userid":"2"}'
'{"id":"5","userid":"3"}'
```

now I need to execute this query :

```
select count(userid),userid from my-index  group by userid having count(userid)=3;
```

Is it possible to execute such queries in elasticsearch?

Answer (score 3):

You can use terms aggregation along with [bucket selector aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html)

Adding a working example with index mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "userid": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "userId": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "userid"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "the_filter": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "the_doc_count": "_count"
            },
            "script": "params.the_doc_count == 3"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "userId": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "1",              // this denotes the userid having count==3
          "doc_count": 3
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: @Milux please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: @Milux can you please accept and upvote the answer, if it helped you resolve your issue :)